# Rotate 3D Object with finger touch Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to rotate a ball when swiping left & right anywhere on the screen, so I made the script bellow, but the ball is rotating only when I swipe directly on the ball not anywhere on the screen, do you have any idea?

Ball Script:

```
 private float baseAngle = 0.0f;
public Camera cam;

void OnMouseDown()
{
    Vector3 pos = cam.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);
    pos = Input.mousePosition - pos;
    baseAngle = Mathf.Atan2(pos.y, pos.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    baseAngle -= Mathf.Atan2(transform.right.y, transform.right.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
}

void OnMouseDrag()
{
    Vector3 pos = cam.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);
    pos = Input.mousePosition - pos;
    float ang = Mathf.Atan2(pos.y, pos.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg - baseAngle;
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(-ang, Vector3.up);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your trouble is that the script you provided is attached to the ball itself, so touches (clicks) are processed only by the ball. In other word methods `OnMouseDown` and `OnMouseDrag` are called only when the touch(click) hits the ball. See the [Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown.html). It says:

> OnMouseDown is called when the user has pressed the mouse button while over the GUIElement or Collider.

There are at least to ways to get what you want:

- If you want to get touched everywhere on the screen create a separate gameobject (empty and containing only a collider and your script) and make it collider Bounds fit the screen. Then add a public transform field to your script and assign the ball's transform to make it possible to rotate ball from the other script
- Use methods from `Input` class instead of `OnMouseDown` and `OnMouseDrag`. For example [Input.GetMouseButton](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetMouseButton.html) - it is called every time user click mouse button ( or touch) no matter, what click hit.

Comment: If you have a custom camera script, sure, why not. If you're talking about the first way, the only requirement for the gameobject is to have a collider, fitting all the screen